# Quotation marks for Swiss text

Tags: html, css, internationalization

For a Swiss website in need the proper quotation marks to be set for `<q>` tagged content for Swiss, German and French language.
The HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de-CH">
...
<p>Lorem <q>ipsum</q> dolor sit amet</p>
```

the styles

```css
q[lang="de-CH"] {
  quotes: '«' '»' '‹' '›';
}
```

The quotes used (Edge) are `„` and `‟` which are the default German quotations not the specified Swiss one's. If I add `lang="de-CH"` to `<q>` it does work but I do not want to specify this in the text, it should take it from the `<html lang` setting. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block then should be

```
html[lang="de-CH"] q {
  quotes: '«' '»' '‹' '›';
}
```

so you change the quotes for `q` when `html` has `lang=de-CH`. (the `html` part may be omitted so to decrease the specificity of the selector)

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly. could you add a css to the ``` for formatting. And perhaps add these for completeness. `html[lang="de"] q{
  quotes: '„' '“' '‚' '‛';`
}
html[lang="fr"] q{
  quotes: '»' '«' '›' '‹';
}